# Arrangement of isolated variable DC input

Tags: opto-isolator, zener, plc, industrial, digital-isolator

I design isolated DC input for industrial applications that can possibly work from 12 to 24 V.

I add a 5.1 V Zener for over-voltage protection, a capacitor for filtering, and TVS for surge production.

My questions are:

In an overvoltage situation, will any LED light turn on?

Is this the correct arrangement of elements? Can I switch the position for the Zener and capacitor?

[image]

Comment: Your Zener appears to be obsolete and your TVS is not defined so, regards surge withstanding, it's unclear what your aims are. The LED will light on an over-voltage situation and in a normal voltage situation.

Comment: what do you mean by "Zener obsolete "? TVS is SMAJ18CA with 13.7A 29.2V, Is the problem with arrangement or part selection?